# Why does a <div> inside a <div> not notice the outer <div> margin?

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

```
<div id="x">
   <div id="modal-body">
      <div class="modal-input-row">
       xxx
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

#modal-body {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

.modal-input-row {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}
```

When I look at these with Google Chrome developer tools I see that:

- The modal-body top area starts 5rem below the #x `<div>`
- The modal-input-row top area starts 5rem below the #x `<div>`

As modal-input-row is inside modal-body then whey does it not start 7rem below the #x `<div>` ?

Comment: The modal-input-row top area starts 5rem OR 2rem below the #x?

Answer (score 4):

What you're seeing is a case known as [margin collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing). It happens under several conditions, and yours is known as the scenario where there is no clearance between the top margin of the parent and the first child.

> If there is no border, padding, inline content, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block with the margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block with the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

It would be advisable to use paddings instead, as they don't collapse.

Margin collapse is also discussed in greater detail in the [W3C box model specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins)

Comment: Thanks. I will check this out. I was not aware of such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML, `modal-input-row` is a class.

CSS markup should be

```
.modal-input-row {
    margin-top: 2rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}
```

OR:

Change

```
<div class="modal-input-row">
```

to

```
<div id="modal-input-row">
```

Comment: Sorry but it was my mistake in entering the question. In my HTML and CSS it is a class.

Answer (score 0):

As per this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gjNAW/ It seems to be fine.

Borders absence is making it collapse.

See this one without borders: http://jsfiddle.net/gjNAW/1/

Aside:

(1) you misplaced the "." for the class.

(2) no need to explicitly specify `display:block`, because divs are block elements.